# Navigation property mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework-6, automapper

i nedd to mapping the property navigation.
my case :> 
i have a class "Listing"

```
public class Listing {
        public int OfficeId {get;set;}
        public int PropertyCountryId { get; set; }
        public string PropertyPostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

and "ListingViewModel"

```
public class ListingViewModel
    {
        public LocationViewModel Location { get; set; }
        public int OfficeId { get; set; }       
    }
```

i need to map "PropertyCountryId" and "PropertyPostalCode" to my ViewModel "LocationViewModel" from "Listing".
the automapper configuration:

```
CreateMap<Listing, ListingViewModel>()
 .ForMember(dest => dest.Location, map => map.MapFrom(
                source => new Location
                {
                    PropertyCountryId= source.PropertyCountryId,
                    PropertyPostalCode= source.PropertyPostalCode,
                }
                ));
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
>   Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
>   For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters

Comment: Do you have a no-arg constructor in ListingViewModel ?

Comment: no, i don' have any constructor in ListingViewModel

Comment: Does `ListingViewModel` have any other properties? Because once I fix the typo in the Automapper config (`new Location` should be `new LocationViewModel`), it compiles and runs fine for me.

Comment: @asherber As I see it, there is no typo. He wants to bind a `new Location` object on the `Location` property of the `ListingViewModel`. It would be better with a mapping from `Listing` to `Location`, yet it should still work (it does when I try it). The problem must come from somewhere else.

Comment: @krimog i create a mapping from Listing to Location but not work for me, the same error always !

Comment: @krimog The `Location` property is of type `LocationViewModel`. The code as given does not compile for me, because the code has `new Location()`, and there is no type `Location` defined. Nevertheless, I am not able to reproduce the OP's error about 'Unmapped members' with the code as shown. I suspect that there is something we're not seeing here.